# Dropdown is displaying the content above the dropdown control, it is not displaying the content below the control in uwp

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have created a combobox button in uwp and added some items in it, but when i click on that combo box at run time it is showing me content or the list of items above the combo box. It should be shown below the control. Is there any way to implement so in uwp.

```
`</Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ComboBox Height="30" Width="220" x:Name="dropDown"></ComboBox>
 </Grid>`

`code behind: 
            dropDown.Items.Add("Mobile");
            dropDown.Items.Add("Phone");
            dropDown.Items.Add("Car");
            dropDown.Items.Add("EarPhone");`
```

[image]

Comment: Does the following works?

Comment: No, i am seeing no DropDownControl in uwp.

Comment: DropDownButton avaiable in   Windows 10, version 1809 (introduced v10.0.17763.0). Please set your app's target min version to 1809

Comment: The project i am working on is set with min target version 1803. What can i do in that case.

Comment: Please use `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` nuget package within your project for more please refer the following update

Comment: Do you have any updates for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

> Dropdown is displaying the content above the dropdown control, it is not displaying the content below the control in uwp

The display air in above screenshot rendered with `Popup` control that will set position adaptive. If you do want to make dropdown  display in the bottom please try to use [`DropDownButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.dropdownbutton?view=winui-2.2) control

```
<DropDownButton Content="Email">
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Send"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reply"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reply All"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

**Update**

If your target min version is 1803, you could install [`Microsoft.UI.Xaml`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml/2.0.181018003)(version 2.0.181018003) nuget package that contains `DropDownButton`.

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"

<muxc:DropDownButton Content="Email">
    <muxc:DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Send"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reply"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Reply All"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </muxc:DropDownButton.Flyout>
</muxc:DropDownButton>
```